# Battery voltage monitor even if it is charging

Tags: battery-charging, voltage-monitor

I am working on a project and I want to add a battery voltage monitoring feature to it. The battery is 3.7 V and I want to monitor its voltage level with the ADC even if it is charging. The main problem is I don't have much space inside the enclosure and I want to add a small circuit to do the job. Someone suggested a diode which can isolate the charger voltage from the battery voltage while connected to the ADC but I don't know how it works? Can someone please guide me?

I came across all the similar questions but all of them address different topics.

Comment: How is measuring a battery's voltage when it is charging different from when it is not charging? IOW, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to isolate the charger voltage from the battery voltage on the ADC pin when the charger is plugged in. I want to monitor the battery voltage only.

Comment: Presumably, when the battery is charging, it is connected to the charging voltage so the battery voltage is the same as the charging voltage. You can't "isolate" them because they are the same.

Comment: So how can I measure the voltage while charging, how can I know if the battery is full or still charging?

Comment: @WaqasAhmad When you say isolate, do you mean voltage isolation (meaning using a transformer or capaictor to prevent ESD or arcing with a circuit?) or do you mean buffering?

Comment: By isolation I mean only reading the battery voltage level and avoiding charger voltage for a brief time so that I can determine if the battery is fully charged or not

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do to monitor the battery voltage with the MCU ADC. The first problem is the voltage range of the MCU ADC, they are usually 3.3V so 3.7V would activate the ESD/overvoltage diode or burn out the MCU ADC port (unless it is 5V tolarant, but in that case you would not be able to read 3.3V, the measured voltage would 'rail out').

So at minimum you would need a voltage divider circuit to get 3.7V-4.2V attenuated to 3.3V a voltage divider with a ratio of ~ 0.75 of vin to vout. You can make a voltage divider be very small, there is some error and leakage associated with a voltage divider. Make sure you use large resistors (like above 100k) but also account for the input bias current of the ADC.

You could also use an opamp with a gain of 0.75.